# Spawn mongo server and express asynchronous sever setup script for local and docker deployment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, mean-stack

I'm new to MEAN stack development and was wondering whats the ideal way to spin an mongo+express environment.

Running synchronous bash script commands make the mongo server stop further execution and listen for connections. What would be a local + docker compatible script to initiate the environment ?

Answer (score 0):

Many people use docker-compose for a situation like this. You can set up a docker-compose configuration file where you describe services that you would like to run. Each service defines a docker image. In your case, you could have mongodb, your express app and your angular app defined as services. Then, you can launch the whole stack with `docker-compose up`.

A sample docker-compose config file would look something like:

```
version: '2' # specify docker-compose version

# Define the services/containers to be run
services:
  angular: # name of the first service
    build: angular-client # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4200:4200" # specify port forewarding

  express: #name of the second service
    build: express-server # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" #specify ports forewarding

  database: # name of the third service
    image: mongo # specify image to build container from
    ports:
      - "27017:27017" # specify port forewarding
```

which comes from an article here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-mean-app-with-angular-2-and-docker-compose